# How to check line in file (php)

Tags: php, string, file, passwords, line

I'm new to php and wanted to make a simple php script to check a form of my html site.

To answer the questions:
I have a file, that's the Name of the User and I want to check if the password that is in there (line 1) is the same as the one in the "password" field on my site. And when it's like this it should open a site.

Maybe a check if the file exists would be nice :D

This is my php-file, it's named "check.php":

```
<?php

    $f = fopen($_POST["name"], "r");

    $theData = fgets($f);

    if ($_POST["pw"] == $theData) {
        $ch = curl_init("site.com");
        curl_exec($ch);
    }

    fclose($f);
?>
```

This is my html-file:

```
<h2>Check</h2>
<form action="check.php" method='post'>
    <b>Name: </b><input name="name" type="text" value="Name"> <br>
    <b>Password: </b><input name="pw" type="text" value="Passwort"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Check">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I hope one can help me ^^
I've tried a lot of things now, nothing really worked.

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify your issue / question a bit?

Comment: why you have written fopen? is their any file which you want to open?

Comment: he tries to check the password against a value stored in a file. Then he wants to redirect the user to another page (using curl??)

Comment: I clearified it all now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process a form fields you should do like this in your check.php file(simplest one)

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_PSOT['name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($name == 'admin' && $password == 'admin')
        {
            header('Location:admin.php');exit;
        }else{
            echo 'Wrong user name or password';
        }
    }

may be you are asking to do like this
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_PSOT['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $file_type = '.txt';
    $path = 'path to folder/'.$name.$file_type;
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        $user_pass = fopen($path, "r");
        $flag = 0;
        while(!feof($user_pass)) 
        {
            $p = fgets($user_pass);
            if($password == $p)
            {
                $flag = 1;
            }
        }
        fclose($user_pass);
        if($flag == 1)
        {
            header('Location:to your page link/weblink');exit;
        }else{
            echo 'Wrong password';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'User does not exists';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok but I thought I could get the password from a file and it's not in the code itself. I could make it like this but I want to learn how to use php so I want to know how to get things out of a file and check it with given things like inputs from an html file :D